# Deploy wlapp files in MFP Liberty using ant

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli

I'm trying to deploy wlapp file in MFP Liberty Server using ant task.
I created the build.xml then run "ant" in cmd.

```
C:\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\shortcuts>ant
Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\IBM\Installation Manager\e
clipse\jre_7.0.9030.20160210_1426\lib\tools.jar
Buildfile: C:\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\shortcuts\build.xml

install:
    [wladm] The REST service URL http://IP:9080/worklightconsol
e cannot be accessed in a secure way. You may want to use a https URL instead, o
r retry with the 'secure' option set to 'false'.

BUILD FAILED
C:\IBM\MobileFirst_Platform_Server\shortcuts\build.xml:9: com.ibm.worklight.admi
n.restclient.RESTException: The REST service URL http://IP:9080
/worklightconsole cannot be accessed in a secure way. You may want to use a http
s URL instead, or retry with the 'secure' option set to 'false'.
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.checkURI(RESTClient.jav
a:1001)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getPOSTResponse(RESTCli
ent.java:1433)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.RESTClient.getPOSTFileResponse(RES
TClient.java:1464)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.commands.DeployApp.getResponse(DeployApp.java
:41)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.restclient.ActionClient.execute(ActionClient.
java:84)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.types.AbstractActionElement.executeComman
d(AbstractActionElement.java:76)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.types.ActionElement.executeCommands(Actio
nElement.java:43)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.WladmTask.executeCommands(WladmTask.java:
705)
        at com.ibm.worklight.admin.ant.WladmTask.execute(WladmTask.java:459)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:56)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:392)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:413)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:811)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 1 second
```

I don't know where to set the "secure to false" but I tried this one:

```
wladm --url= --user= ... [--passwordfile=...] [--secure=false]
```

It says:

```
Secure mode is enabled, but an option '--passwordfile' is missing.
```

Anyone know where to change the secure to false since the url is just http and not https?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more details, please refer to the wladm usage documentation at http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.appadmin.doc/admin/r_invoking_the_wladm_program.html.

Comment: I tried to enter some commands but it keeps saying "A password is required, but an option '--passwordfile' is missing." 
Example fof what I tried
>wladm --url=http://IP:PORT --user=demo --secure=false show version

Comment: I tried to add the --passwordfile=PATH/wladm.config in the command and it now display this error... http://IP:PORT/userAndConfigInfo?locale=en_US: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're supposed to keep the square brackets in the command.
Try without. Simply `--secure=false`.

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: If I enter that in cmd, it goes to another line..
wlcmd> and I need to enter another command..

Comment: Yes, if you provided no command (such as "deploy app ...") on the command line, wladm goes into an interactive prompt loop, with "wladm>" as prompt, that allows you to enter the command (and possibly additional commands) there.